# Can I control which consensus node I want to submit my transaction to from the client?

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

I'm using Javascript SDK. Currently it seems random. I'm wanting to submit to a specific node to reduce latency

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that. You can specify a consensus node you want to submit the transaction to like the example below.

```
 const customClient = Client.forNetwork(node).setMirrorNetwork(
   "custom.mirrornode.com:5600"
 );
```